# Python Recursion - return values using a bool operator

Tags: python, recursion, boolean-logic

I have a recursive function called eval() that in one case returns:

```
 base case: ...

 if some_case():
        return eval() and eval()
```

That was my first attempt, which did not return the expected result.
unlike what I believe to be that an equivalent code:

```
 if base case():
     ...

 if some_case():     
    add_first = eval()
    add_second = eval()
    return add_first and add_second
```

which seemed to to the trick.

Would like an explanation on the difference.
any ideas?

Comment: Don't call it `eval`, since that's a builtin Python function.  But to answer your question, the `and` operator will not evaluate its second operand if the first operand evaluates to false.

Comment: Sounds like a shortcut evaluation problem. btw isn't `eval()` a builtin function?

Comment: @TomKarzes your right ,the eval was just for the code example :)

Comment: @quamrana indeed that answers it as well, thank you!